# ActiveAdmin, datetime & Strong Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a model called 'Trainers' with a datetime field called `scheduled_interview` which is editable in ActiveAdmin:

`f.input :scheduled_interview`

This creates 5 `<select>`s (for year, month, day, hours & mins).

I've tried adding each of:

`permit_params :scheduled_interview => []`

and:

`permit_params scheduled_interview: []`

into `ActiveAdmin.register Trainer do ...`

But when submitting the form, I see:

`Unpermitted parameters: scheduled_interview(1i), scheduled_interview(2i), scheduled_interview(3i), scheduled_interview(4i), scheduled_interview(5i)`

What am I doing wrong with the strong parameters?

**Edit 1:** this is using Rails 4, which I wasn't clear about.

**Edit 2:**

In the trainer controller:

```
def create
  @trainer = Trainer.new(application_params)
end

def application_params
  params.require(:trainer).permit(
    :name, :email, :scheduled_interview: []
  )
end
```

Using just `:scheduled_interview` generates the same error as above.

**Edit 3:**

Log when saving trainer:

```
Started PATCH "/admin/prospective_trainers/trainer-id" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-07-06 17:49:36 +0000
Processing by Admin::ProspectiveTrainersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "prospective_trainers"=>{"name"=>"trainer name", "email"=>"email@emailaddres.com", "scheduled_interview(1i)"=>"2014", "scheduled_interview(2i)"=>"7", "scheduled_interview(3i)"=>"15", "scheduled_interview(4i)"=>"16", "scheduled_interview(5i)"=>"15"}, "commit"=>"Update Trainer", "id"=>"trainer-id"}
  AdminUser Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = 8 ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Trainer Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "trainers".* FROM "trainers" WHERE "trainers"."slug" = 'trainer-id' ORDER BY "trainers"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: scheduled_interview(1i), scheduled_interview(2i), scheduled_interview(3i), scheduled_interview(4i), scheduled_interview(5i)
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, _method, commit, id
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/prospective_trainers/trainer-id
  Trainer Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "trainers".* FROM "trainers" WHERE "trainers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 327]]
Completed 302 Found in 167ms (ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)
```

All other fields save just fine (name, email etc).

Comment: Can you post your `strong params` method of your controller? And also what happens when you just give it like `:scheduled_interview`?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated with the controller. `:scheduled_interview` generates the same error.

Comment: Can you post the server log generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: within ActiveAdmin's `trainer.rb` I had mistakenly placed 2 `permit_params`, the 2nd overriding the first. Fixed as follows:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Trainer, as: "Prospective Trainers" do
    permit_params :name, :email, :scheduled_interview
```

Also removed `:scheduled_interview` from my trainer controller's `params.require(:trainer).permit(...` as it doesn't have any bearing on ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `:scheduled_interview` to your Trainers controller. Not to ActiveAdmin. ActiveAdmin just goes through your regular models and controllers, it isn't the correct place to assign parameters.

Comment: But in Rails 4 this is handled in controllers rather than models, I believe? I also ran through this Active Admin guide re. strong params: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters

Comment: yeah woops wrong word sorry. I corrected it to say trainers controller.